# Spectral density for the operator $A u = - u''$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

How to prove that the spectral density for the operator $A u = - u''$ on the whole real line is 
$$ e(x,y;\lambda) = \frac{\chi(\lambda) \, cos\lambda^{1/2} (x-y)}{2\pi \lambda^{1/2}} $$
where $\chi $ is the Heaviside function.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Let $s=\sqrt{\lambda}$ in the following, with $ds = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\lambda}}d\lambda$,
$$
      \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\frac{\cos\sqrt{\lambda}(x-y)}{2\pi\sqrt{\lambda}}dy\right)d\lambda \\
  = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\cos s(x-y)dy\right)ds \\
  = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\cos(sy)dy\cos(sx)ds
   + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\sin(sy)dy\sin(sx)ds \\
  = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\cos(sy)dy\cos(sx)ds+\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\sin(sy)dy\sin(sx)ds
$$
You can also write the original expression in terms of the exponential form.

Comment: good evening T.A.E. is what you can detail your proof a little because I did not understand how you calculated $e(\lambda,x,y)$. is what you calculated \the spectral density $e_\lambda$ or the spectral family $E_\lambda$? Tank you in advance

Comment: @Z.Alfata : I didn't calculate it. I showed you that it is what you claim it to be by integrating the density to obtain the identity operator expressed, in this case, as the Fourier transforms and their inverses.